# Grammatical terminology for the difference between 'hear' and 'listen'

Tags: terminology

Is there any grammatical terminology to describe the difference between 'hear' and 'listen'?

E.g.

*Hear* is a ____ verb and *listen* is its ____ counterpart.

Or,

*Hear-listen* is a pair of ____ words.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the term you're looking for is *volition*.

> *Listen* is a **volitional** verb and *hear* is its **non-volitional** counterpart.

When you listen to something, you're paying attention to it on purpose.

---

Here's how the term is defined in David Crystal's *A Dictionary of Linguistics and Phonetics, 6th ed.*:

> **volition** (*n.*) A term used in the semantic analysis of grammatical categories, referring to a kind of relationship between an agent and a verb. A **volitional** verb or construction is one where the action takes place as a consequence of the agent's choice, e.g. *Mary left*. A **non-volitional** verb or construction is one where the agent has no determining influence on the action, e.g. *Mary slipped*.  Many verbs allow both interpretations (e.g. *X hit Y* – accidentally or on purpose?). The notion has also had a contrastive role in the analysis of the meanings of certain auxiliary verbs in English: for example, the volitional sense of *will* in *I will go* (in the sense of 'it is my decision to go') is distinguished from other senses, such as characteristic action (*They'll sit there for hours*).

(p.516)

Answer (score 6):

*Hear* is **transitive** and in its root sense **telic**: it requires a direct object, and it ordinarily designates a **'achievement'**, a change of state: you become aware of something which you were not aware of previously.

*Listen* is **intransitive** and **atelic**: it does not take a direct object (something which is actually heard when you are listening is designated by the object of a preposition), and it ordinarily designates an **'activity'**, a continuing investment of energy in maintaining a state of awareness.

The terms *telic, atelic, achievement* and *activity* are discussed in a little more depth at the tag-wiki on [aspect](https://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).

Comment: I would have guessed the OP was looking for *non-volitional* and *volitional*.

Comment: @snailboat Some folks only hear what they wanta hear.

Comment: So, @StoneyB, is the sense of *see* in I saw the accident telic, where as the sense of *see* in I've seen the film atelic? (And is *watch* atelic too?)

Comment: So, @StoneyB, is the sense of *see* in *I saw the accident* telic, and the sense of *see* in *I've seen the film* atelic? (And is *watch* atelic too?)

Comment: @Araucaria Both *see*s are telic, and *watch* is atelic - try the "for an hour" test. The *see*s differ perhaps in *durativity*, but that's a function of the different objects. Lexical aspect gets harder to discern (and less significant) in *perfective* contexts, which is what you get with preterites.

Comment: @snailboat Actually you are right - volition is the concept I am after. I did not look up for linguistic meaning for telicity, only looked at a dictionary explanation for the word telic and thought it meant volitional.

Comment: @NS.X. In that case you should un-accept this answer, and ask snailboat to expand on her answer so you can accept that.  That way the right answer will be readily available to anyone else who has the same question.

Comment: @snailboat Would you like to put your comment into an answer so I can accept that?

Comment: @StoneyB What's the *for an hour* test? (Have you imbibed so much knowledge that you can't remember what it's like for us mortals?) I don't understand yet how *I saw the film* and *I watched the film* differ ... :( [which prolly is cuz I don't fully understand *telic* and *atelic* :D]

Comment: @Araucaria ① I ate an apple in an hour. `[+telic +telic]` ② \*I ate apples in an hour. `[-telic +telic]` ③ ??I ate an apple for an hour. `[+telic -telic]` ④ I ate apples for an hour. `[-telic -telic]`

Comment: @snailboat Oh, I seem to have hit an understanding barrier :( Stoney tried to explain it to me before, but I'm failing miserably ... What's your explanation of *telic* for dummies like me? (Actually I'm not *too* worried about being not very good at understanding some stuff, but i *do* like to understand! - and so would be very grateful!) Oh!, and I do happen to understand that many congrats are in order?

Comment: @Araucaria Sorry, thought I'd told you the in/for timespan test last time. Take a look [here](http://ell.stackexchange.com/tags/aspect/info).