# To hear or to listen?

Tags: word-difference, verb-usage

So I was about to tell someone that he shouldn't ---------that, because it wasn't something delightful to-----------. What verb should I use in this case?

Comment: This might be helpful [What is the difference between 'hear' and 'listen'?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/9054)

Comment: He shouldn't say that because it wasn't a good thing thing for others to hear. It's not very idiomatic to say/write: something delightful to hear. Things you hear can be said to be: interesting, good, bad, boring, etc. Experiences and situations are delightful, usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably two different verbs:  "listen to" and "hear".

"Listen to" means to *intentionally* hear, whereas "hear" by itself only refers to the physical operation of sound getting to the brain.  "Listen to" and "hear" are comparable to "say" and "speak".  "Speak" is physical, "say" is intentional.